# Unterschied zwischen "auf etwas ankommen" und "von etwas abhängen"

Tags: word-usage, difference, synonym

*(Aus der Zeitung)*

- Frage:

  > Welche Rolle spielt die Lebensdauer von Produkten für Konsumenten bei der Kaufentscheidung?
- Antwort:

  > (Es) kommt auf das Produkt an.

Könnte die Antwort auch wie folgt lauten?

> (Es) hängt von dem Produkt ab.

Also, besteht ein Unterschied zwischen den beiden Ausdrücken oder gelten sie als synonym?

Comment: Das kommt drauf an...

Answer (score 5):

Ja, meiner Meinung nach kann die Antwort auch "Es hängt von dem Produkt ab" lauten. Das beschreibt die Abhängigkeit von der Lebensdauer des Produktes und der Kaufentscheidung der Konsumenten.

Answer (score 4):

> Also, besteht ein Unterschied zwischen den beiden Ausdrücken oder gelten sie als synonym?

**In the given context the meaning of these two expressions is basically the same.**

I'd say this corresponds to **point 7** in the list of meanings of ***[ankommen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ankommen)*** at *duden.de*

> **7.  von jemandem, etwas abhängen**
>
> *Beispiele*
>      auf ihn, seine Initiative, auf den Stand der Dinge, auf einen Versuch kommt es an
>       auf ein paar Euro kommt es mir nicht an
>       es kommt aufs Wetter an, ob wir morgen fahren können
>       er glaubt, es käme auf ihn an (er hält sich für besonders wichtig)
>
> *Wendungen, Redensarten, Sprichwörter*
>      es auf etwas ankommen lassen (vor etwas nicht zurückschrecken, etwas riskieren: es auf einen Versuch, einen Prozess mit jemandem ankommen lassen)
>       es d[a]rauf ankommen lassen (umgangssprachlich; abwarten, wie etwas kommt, wie sich etwas von selbst fügt)

And to **point 3 a** in the list of meanings of ***[abhängen (starkes verb)](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abhaengen_starkes_Verb)***

> **3. a. durch etwas bedingt sein; jemandes Willen oder Macht unterworfen sein**
>
> *Beispiele*
>       etwas hängt von den Umständen, vom Wetter, vom Zufall ab
>       ihre Zukunft hing von dieser Entscheidung ab

Also note the other meanings.

Answer (score 3):

As correctly stated by user 5513, in the given context (the complete phrase „it depends on...“) they are interchangeable.

**There are, however, some important and less obvious cases in which only one can be used** [I am not going into almost unrelated meanings, such as „abhängen mit Freunden“ (slang) or „gut abgehangenes Fleisch“].

### When to only use *abhängen*

In a mathematical context

> Q hängt von x und y ab./Q depends on x and y.

### When to only use *darauf ankommen*

When stressing *what matters*.

> Herr Kommerzialrat! Warum haben Sie den Jungen eingestellt? Er hat nicht einmal die Matura!/Sir, (honorary title for Austrian businessmen left untranslated) why did you employ the youngster? He didn’t even complete secondary school!
>
> Die Matura ist unwichtig! Auf den Scharfsinn kommt es an!/Completing secondary school is irrelevant! Acumen matters!

This is because under *ankommen* [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ankommen) lists (among lots of other meanings):

- von jemandem, etwas abhängen
- [für jemanden] wichtig, von Bedeutung
  sein

It is the second usage we see above. Note also:

> Das, worauf es in einer Beziehung wirklich ankommt, ist.../The thing that really matters in a relationship is...